# Is there a way to send my Chrome Extension to testers before it being approved?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension, and have sent it for approval trough the Google Web Store Developer Dashboard. When I completed the process, I was informed that it may take several weeks for my extension to be reviwed for publishing. I chose to publish it only for testing. Is there a way for me to have some friends download it and test it before the reviewing process is complete? Thank you.

Comment: You might know about this already.. Here you go about loading unpacked extension in your friends browser.. https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-install-the-unpacked-extension-in-chrome/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized later that after sending the extension for review, I can see a link for the extension in the store. This link is not publicly available, and can only be acessed by myself and accounts that I add as trusted testers on my "Account" page. After adding the e-mails for my friends, I can send them the link, and they will be able to download the extension from there. (The authorization for the testers has a small delay, but usually after 5 minutes they are able to see the extension page). This was exactly what I needed, and I think is simpler then sending the code to my friends.

Comment: yeah this does not work for me.. Added people to trusted accounts, but still does not work.. quite unfortuante.

Comment: Did you give it a few minutes? Also, make sure that everything went well with your package upload.

Comment: This does not work for me either, even after a few hours! I think the extension still has to pass review even for trusted testers, and maybe the docs are out of date?

Comment: @GautamBose, hmm, I don't think that was the case back when I did this, but maybe they changed it...

Comment: where do you exactly see that link? I want to test my extension with few beta testers.

Comment: @Nithur did you find the link? Same situation here, submitted for review but want to share with friends

Comment: @Bayram, add a few people to your trusted accounts and go to your items and on top you'll see an option to preview your item. It will take you to the preview your item in the store. Remove the preview part from the URL and copy it.

Comment: @Nithur when I go to items, I see archive button, when I click I see the extension in pending review. Don't see any preview option.

Comment: @Bayram click on the item and in the top right menu you can see the button to go to the preview page

Comment: Thanks @Nithur, yes there is Preview options, I didn't see it but it was also approved now. I submitted new update for review but that link is now public, can it be also used to share new update as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind sharing the code with your friends, you can simply send them the folder of your extension. Then your friends can go to chrome://extensions/ turn on the developer mode and load the extension the same way you do when developing.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still having this issue, here is how I fixed it.

- Go to Chrome Web Developer Dashboard
- Click on your item (Extension)
- Navigate to distribution tab
- Change visibility to Private if you want do just make it available
  for testers or trusted emails
  [image: Visibility settings]

Then, click on the two links highlighted in the image above, "settings page" and "Google Group".

On Google group's page, I've created a new group following the instructions, added every tester email I wanted, and made them owners of this group.

On the settings page, management section, I've also added the tester emails there separated by a comma. Remeber to save changes on the button down the page.

After all of this configuration is done go to your items and on top right corner you'll see three dots, click on it, select "Preview". It will take you to the extension preview in the store. You'll have a URL like this

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/"EXTENSION_NAME_AND_ID"/preview?hl=en&authuser=1
```

just remove the word "preview" from the url (This page can take up to 5 mins to work after you do the initial configuration)

you should have an URL like this that you can send to your previously configured tester emails

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/EXTENSION_NAME/EXTENSION_ID?hl=en&authuser=1
```